# Parsing JSON returning null

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have the following JSON returned from Facebook:

```
{"id":"123456789","email":"darren@darren.com","first_name":"Darren","gender":"male","last_name":"Sweeney","link":"http://www.facebook.com/123456789","locale":"en_GB","name":"Darren Sweeney","timezone":0,"updated_time":"2014-09-26T22:26:59+0000","verified":true}
```

I'm trying to ajax it to a PHP file for processing but getting `NULL` back from the PHP file:

JQuery:

```
var tmp = JSON.stringify(response);

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/ajax/fbLogin.php',
      data: {'userData': tmp},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['userData'])) {
  $json = $_POST['userData'];
  var_dump(json_decode($json));
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: is the var_dump returning NULL? gotta show your full output.

Comment: var_dump returns NULL - in console because I'm logging NULL it says undefined

Comment: what does the PHP page look like. you can see in the network area in browser dev tools

Comment: perhaps you don't need to JSON.stringify the response you get from facebook.

Comment: `response` in javascript is the `json` code which Facebook returns ? If that is the case, response is already a valid javascript object.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` to ensure your json is coming through ok, then `json_last_error()` to see what the real reason for failure was.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

Posting answer as other users might need this.

As pointed out by @nik in comments, Facebook response does not need processing, so, this now works as it should:

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/ajax/fbLogin.php',
  data: {'userData': response},
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['userData'])) {
  $json = $_POST['userData'];
  var_dump($json);
}
```